# Nuxt 3 + Docker: how to parse request?

Tags: docker, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I have Nuxt 3 app deployed on VPS in a Docker container, so schematically it looks like this:

[image]

I want to grab request headers and get the hostname on the server side with Nuxt.

There are several subdomains on my VPS, so if the client makes request to `app.example.com` I want to parse it in my Nuxt app and put `app.example.com` in a variable before client side is rendered.

I've tried to do this but with no success yet.

```js
// app.vue

<script setup lang="ts">
// execute code on the server side only
if (process.server) {
  const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp()
  const { ssrContext } = nuxtApp
  const headers = useRequestHeaders()
  const event = useRequestEvent()
  const url = useRequestURL()

  console.log(url.host)
  console.log(headers.host)
  console.log(event.node.req.headers.host)
  console.log(srContext.event.node.req.host)
}
</script>
```

All logs output the same:

```
127.0.0.1:3000
127.0.0.1:3000
127.0.0.1:3000
127.0.0.1:3000
```

Nuxt outputs localhost only.

I suppose if I run my Nuxt app without a Docker container it will fix this issue but that's not my case because everything is configured and I have to use Docker.

If Nginx passes client's request to the Nuxt app why can't I get the initial hostname from the request? And how to do this?

Any advice will be appreciated!